# same cgi proxy script behaves differently in 2 different servers

Tags: proxy, cgi

i have one dedicated server and one shared hosting server.

i download and put both cgi proxy script in /cgi-bin/

these two files are identical.

on both servers, i checked that there is no cookies recorded by cgiproxy. virgin.

URL flags are all same.

i navigate to *myspace.com*

**Behavior Difference:**

- dedicated server's cgi proxy
  redirects to google.com
- shared server's cgi proxy
  successfully loads myspace.com

I suspect something wrong with the dedicated server's settings? But what could be wrong or different from the shared hosting ?

Answer (score -1):

Since you've now posted multiple questions about your server being blocked by other web sites, I would guess there's a good chance your server is in a netblock with a bad reputation for abuse.